# War file deployment failed in EAP 6.4

Tags: java, maven, jboss, apache-camel, jboss-eap-6

I am new to `JBoss EAP`, while deploying, I am getting the following error message. Kindly assist me on this. thanks in advance.

```
10:13:54,991 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
10:13:55,179 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry optional/camel-core-2.19.3.jar in /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments/restapi-sample-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/camel-jasypt-2.19.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:13:55,179 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry optional/caffeine-2.4.0.jar in /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments/restapi-sample-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/camel-jasypt-2.19.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:13:55,179 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry optional/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar in /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments/restapi-sample-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/camel-jasypt-2.19.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:13:55,179 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry optional/jasypt-1.9.2.jar in /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments/restapi-sample-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/camel-jasypt-2.19.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:13:55,195 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry optional/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar in /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments/restapi-sample-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/camel-jasypt-2.19.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:13:55,195 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry optional/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar in /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments/restapi-sample-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/camel-jasypt-2.19.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:13:55,210 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments/restapi-sample-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:13:55,226 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments/restapi-sample-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:13:55,257 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-127.0.0.1:8080
10:13:55,319 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-127.0.0.1:8080
10:13:56,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:13:56,835 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.restapi-sample-1.0.0.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.restapi-sample-1.0.0.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.restapi-sample-1.0.0.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:94) [jboss-as-server-7.5.19.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.19.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2064) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1987) [jboss-msc-1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1.jar:1.1.7.SP1-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1055) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1411) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1439) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:71) [jboss-as-server-7.5.19.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.19.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please review this link to help improve your question

Answer (score 0):

The failure for the deployment is because , your application probably needs a jar file or a property file that is required at the time of start up.
 In jboss there is a concept for modules , where you can put in the required files and jboss with associate them up.

In the error logs, it goes and looks up for the required module but is unable to find it and fails.

> org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind:main